# Test the convergence of $\sum _{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \frac{2^k}{2^k+k^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Test the convergence of $\sum _{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \frac{2^k}{2^k+k^2}$

**my idea**

$a_k=\sum _{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \frac{2^k}{2^k+k^2}$

$a_{k+1}=\sum _{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k} \frac{2^{k+1}}{2^{k+1}+(k+1)^2}$

$|\frac{a_{k}}{a_{k+1}}|_{k\to \infty}=\left| \frac{1}{2}\frac{2^{k+1}+(k+1)^2}{2^k+k^2}\right|_{k\to\infty}$

can any help from here please thank you

Answer (score 4):

If the series $\sum_{k>0}a_k$ converges then $a_k\to 0$. So if $\lim_{k\to \infty} a_k \neq 0$ or the limit does not exist then your series diverges. Now calculate:

\begin{align} 
\lim_{k\to \infty} a_k = \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}2^k}{2^k+k^2} =....
\end{align} 
This limit does not exist, can you conclude?

Here is used: "P implies Q" is  equivalent with "not Q implies not P". I hope this helps.

Comment: This is by far the best approach, simple and elegant! +1

Answer (score 0):

Well,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1} 2^k}{2^k+k^2} &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} \frac{2^k+k^2-k^2}{2^k+k^2} \\ 
 &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} \left [ 1 - \frac{k^2}{2^k+k^2} \right ]\\ 
 &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1} k^2}{2^k+k^2}
\end{align*}

The first series obviously diverges whereas the second converges. To see that split it apart. For example

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1} k^2}{2^k+k^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\left \lfloor \frac{2}{\log 2} \right \rfloor} \frac{(-1)^{k-1} k^2}{k^2+2^k} + \sum_{\left \lfloor \frac{2}{\log 2} \right \rfloor+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1} k^2}{2^k+k^2} $$

The first sum is finite , hence convergent , and the second converges since $\displaystyle \lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{k^2}{2^k+k^2} = 0 $ and of course the sequence $\displaystyle a_k = \frac{k^2}{2^k+k^2}$ is decreasing. Here is the [invoked test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Thus your sum diverges.